# How to create App Service Backup Alerts for Failed Backups?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, backup, azure-app-service-plans, azure-alerts

Today my scheduled backup failed and I had to go to the portal to know the reason or monitor the status.

Instead is there a way to configure Backup alerts that notify me the status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct option to select backup failed alerts in Alerts blade as of now however as an alternative you can follow below options to achieve Backup Alerts.

To create the rule, navigate to App Service --> Monitoring --> Alerts.

Click on New alert rule
[image]

Resource will be automatically selected and can edit too.

Next step click on select condition. This will take you to configure signal logic.

Signal Type – All , Monitor Service – All, Select “All Administrative operations" signal name.
[image]

Select Chart period, Select Alert Logic, Event Level – Error, Status - Failed.
[image]

This rule gives all the administrative failed alerts including backup failed alerts with a detailed email.

Then select Action Group if you already have one otherwise click on create action group and create one.
[image]

After adding action group edit click on Email Alert to enter Email or Phone number. Click ok and save changes.
[image]

Then add alert rule name and select resource group in Alert rule details
[image]

Once you create alert rule you will receive and email like below
[image]

Activity log rules take 5 minutes to activate.

You can manage the alert rules by going to Monitoring --> Alerts --> Manage alert rules.

Once the action is triggered you will receive an email notification with detailed description. The below screenshot is an informational level email but as you have enabled for failed operations you will receive an email once an operation is failed.
[image]